# Signing JWT using ES256 on Android

Tags: android, jwt, digital-signature, android-keystore, ecdsa

I am trying to generate a JWT and to sign it with a private key, **on Android** and I am failing to do so because online decoders such as jwt.io or token.dev say that **they could not verify the signature**.

---

#### The requirements are as follow:

- The key must be a P-256 key, meaning EC Algorithm (ECDSA) with SHA-256.
- The header of the token must be as follow:

```
{
  "alg": "ES256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

- and the `payload` must contain an id and the `iat` as follow:

```
{
  "id": "7986f03e-a4b8-4033-87b9-af8ae0468a0b", // it's a UUID and this one is an example
  "iat": 1702390385 // timestamp in seconds from UTC
}
```

I have read the following documentations on Android:

- How to generate a P-256 `KeyPair` and store it in the `Android Key Store`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec#example:-nist-p-256-ec-key-pair-for-signingverification-using-ecdsa
- How to sign (and verfiy signature): https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/cryptography

---

This is the code I am coming up with:

### 1) Generate P-256 Key Pair:

```
// Initialize KeyPairGenerator for ECDSA 256
val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_EC, ANDROID_KEY_STORE)

keyPairGenerator.initialize(
    KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
        keyStoreAlias,
        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN,
    )
        .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"))
        .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
        .build()
)

// Generate the key pair (it will be stored automatically in the Android key store)
keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()
```

### 2)  Create Header & Payload then encode in Base64

```
val encodedHeader = makeJsonAndEncodeToString(
    "alg" to "ES256",
    "typ" to "JWT",
)
val encodedPayload = makeJsonAndEncodeToString(
    "id" to "27d09c71-bd67-4523-97bb-12e933e9acbb",
    "iat" to 1702462854,
)

private fun makeJsonAndEncodeToString(vararg data: Pair<String, Any>): String {
    return Base64.encodeToString(
        JSONObject(data.toMap()).toString().toByteArray(),
        Base64.NO_PADDING or Base64.URL_SAFE or Base64.NO_WRAP,
    )
}
```

### 3)  Sign encoded header & payload then encode in Base64

```
val signatureInput = "$encodedHeader.$encodedPayload"

val keyStore = loadKeyStore() // helper function to load the Android key store

// Retrieve Private Key
val entry: KeyStore.Entry = keyStore.getEntry(keyStoreAlias, null)
if (entry !is KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) {
    throw IllegalStateException("No such private key under the alias <$keyStoreAlias>")
}

// Setup signature & sign input
val ecdsaSign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA")
ecdsaSign.initSign(entry.privateKey)
ecdsaSign.update(signatureInput.toByteArray()) // defaults to UTF-8

val signedContent = ecdsaSign.sign()
val encodedSignature = Base64.encodeToString(
    signedContent, 
    Base64.NO_PADDING or Base64.URL_SAFE or Base64.NO_WRAP,
)

// JWT complete
val token: String = "$encodedHeader.$encodedPayload.$encodedSignature"
```

### 4) Get PEM representation of public key

```
val keyStore = loadKeyStore()
val publicKey = keyStore.getCertificate(keyStoreAlias)?.publicKey ?: return null
val encoded = Base64.encodeToString(publicKey.encoded, Base64.DEFAULT)

return "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n$encoded-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
```

Using this logic, this the final result I get:

```
eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjI3ZDA5YzcxLWJkNjctNDUyMy05N2JiLTEyZTkzM2U5YWNiYiIsImlhdCI6MTcwMjQ2Mjg1NH0.MEQCIGvk2N-3BDf13FAhAywXe7okYH4DygaViBWk6z6wnrvdAiBgJzHegGu8e9YSC9QiKqHvJxjyCRAX53tmmC_LaaFdRQ
```

Jwt.io reports that de decoding was successful but not the signature verification. I made sure to provide the PEM representation of my public key.

**What am I doing wrong here ?**

---

What I did to investigate & debug:

1. I tried to verify the signature using the same instance of `Signature` and using the public key. The result is `true`.
2. I made sure to use the correct flags when encoding in Base64 since I am using the Android Base64. The one from Java.util is not available due to our min SDK being set to 24 (Android 7):

- the token content is encoded in Base64 without padding, safe for URL and without line breaks (no wrap) while
- the PEM representation of the public key is encoded with default flag.

3. I tried to use the `getKey(...)` on the `KeyStore` to retrieve the `PrivateKey` which also works but the signature verification still fails on jwt.io, token.dev, etc.
4. I verified that the PEM representation is also correct. This is my public key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEa5M6OOsgL/+aR4jACkQxnjfRoJgw9fdsYR5ugxC6tBJIZA1oFRpjkc1TdQlbnE7BC6DEbaJPjH3jP0Lcnt2KWQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I was able to validate it with online tools such as: https://report-uri.com/home/pem_decoder. It reports:

```
Public Key Data
Key Algorithm: ECDSA prime256v1
Key Size: 256 bits
Raw Data
Array
(
    [bits] => 256
    [key] => -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEa5M6OOsgL/+aR4jACkQxnjfRoJgw
9fdsYR5ugxC6tBJIZA1oFRpjkc1TdQlbnE7BC6DEbaJPjH3jP0Lcnt2KWQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
    [ec] => Array
        (
            [curve_name] => prime256v1
            [curve_oid] => 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7
            [x] => 6b933a38eb202fff9a4788c00a44319e37d1a09830f5f76c611e6e8310bab412
            [y] => 48640d68151a6391cd5375095b9c4ec10ba0c46da24f8c7de33f42dc9edd8a59
        )

    [type] => 3
)
```

---

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah yes of course, hence the PEM representation I gave here. You can try yourself with the JWT I generated & signed and with the PEM representation of my public key and you'll see the signature verification fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong signature format, namely the ASN.1/DER encoding of the ECDSA signature. For JWT, the IEEE P1363 format (r|s) is required, see [RFC 7518, sec 3.4](https://github.com/hierynomus/asn-one).

---

The following test shows that the wrong format is the cause of the problem: If in your signature:

```
eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjI3ZDA5YzcxLWJkNjctNDUyMy05N2JiLTEyZTkzM2U5YWNiYiIsImlhdCI6MTcwMjQ2Mjg1NH0.MEQCIGvk2N-3BDf13FAhAywXe7okYH4DygaViBWk6z6wnrvdAiBgJzHegGu8e9YSC9QiKqHvJxjyCRAX53tmmC_LaaFdRQ
```

the signature part is *manually* converted from ASN.1/DER to the IEEE P1363 format (s. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/57731)), the following signed JWT results:

```
eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjI3ZDA5YzcxLWJkNjctNDUyMy05N2JiLTEyZTkzM2U5YWNiYiIsImlhdCI6MTcwMjQ2Mjg1NH0.a-TY37cEN_XcUCEDLBd7uiRgfgPKBpWIFaTrPrCeu91gJzHegGu8e9YSC9QiKqHvJxjyCRAX53tmmC_LaaFdRQ
```

which can be [successfully verified](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjI3ZDA5YzcxLWJkNjctNDUyMy05N2JiLTEyZTkzM2U5YWNiYiIsImlhdCI6MTcwMjQ2Mjg1NH0.a-TY37cEN_XcUCEDLBd7uiRgfgPKBpWIFaTrPrCeu91gJzHegGu8e9YSC9QiKqHvJxjyCRAX53tmmC_LaaFdRQ&publicKey=-----BEGIN%20PUBLIC%20KEY-----%0AMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEa5M6OOsgL%2F%2BaR4jACkQxnjfRoJgw9fdsYR5ugxC6tBJIZA1oFRpjkc1TdQlbnE7BC6DEbaJPjH3jP0Lcnt2KWQ%3D%3D%0A-----END%20PUBLIC%20KEY-----) on jwt.io with the public key you posted. This shows that the signature itself is correct and the problem is only caused by the format.

---

To fix the code, apply `SHA256withPlain-ECDSA` instead of `SHA256withECDSA` for a signature in IEEE P1363 format (if necessary using BouncyCastle).

---

**Edit:** The conversion from ASN.1/DER format to P1363 format can also be implemented by yourself with an ASN.1/DER parser, e.g. with [hierynomus/asn-one](https://github.com/hierynomus/asn-one).
Then, `SHA256withECDSA` can still be used (so that BouncyCastle is not necessary). The ASN.1/DER signature is simply converted to the P1363 format afterwards. This could be implemented e.g. as follows:

```kotlin
import com.hierynomus.asn1.ASN1InputStream
import com.hierynomus.asn1.encodingrules.der.DERDecoder
import com.hierynomus.asn1.types.constructed.ASN1Sequence
...
fun toP1363(derSignature: ByteArray, size: Int) : ByteArray {
    val stream = ASN1InputStream(DERDecoder(), derSignature)
    val sequence = stream.readObject<ASN1Sequence>() 
    val r = (sequence.get(0).value as BigInteger).toString(16).padStart(size, '0')
    val s = (sequence.get(1).value as BigInteger).toString(16).padStart(size, '0')
    return (r + s).hexStringToByteArray()
}
fun String.hexStringToByteArray() = this.chunked(2).map { it.toInt(16).toByte() }.toByteArray()
```

with the following dependency in the *gradle build script*:

```
implementation 'com.hierynomus:asn-one:0.6.0'
```

Test:

```kotlin
val signedContent = Base64.decode("MEQCIGvk2N-3BDf13FAhAywXe7okYH4DygaViBWk6z6wnrvdAiBgJzHegGu8e9YSC9QiKqHvJxjyCRAX53tmmC_LaaFdRQ", Base64.NO_WRAP or Base64.URL_SAFE or Base64.NO_PADDING)
val encodedSignature = Base64.encodeToString(
    toP1363(signedContent, 64),
    Base64.NO_PADDING or Base64.URL_SAFE or Base64.NO_WRAP,
)
println(encodedSignature) // a-TY37cEN_XcUCEDLBd7uiRgfgPKBpWIFaTrPrCeu91gJzHegGu8e9YSC9QiKqHvJxjyCRAX53tmmC_LaaFdRQ
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks promising. However I have trouble switching to  `SHA256withPlain-ECDSA` but it does indeed seem to require BouncyCastle. I have therefore added 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.77' (the project support JDK 17), but BouncyCastle failed saying: "cannot identify EC private key: java.security.InvalidKeyException: no encoding for EC private key". My key was previously generated with the Android Key Store (see my code in OP). I still to use the Android Key Store. Is that possible ?

Comment: @Mackovich - If BouncyCastle is not an option (due to the keystore problem), you can also use a library with which a conversion from ASN.1/DER to P1363 is *directly* possible. Alternatively, this can be implemented with an ASN.1 parser by yourself. Then `SHA256withECDSA` can still be used, see the edit section of my answer for a sample code.

Comment: I thank you a lot for that detailed and complete solution. Unfortunately, due to time constraints, I had to find another solution and I am now using JJWT (https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) which does not require `BouncyCastle` and is working fine with my current key implementation logic. It also handles, JWT and generation + Base64 encoding. The code is much shorter and simpler and the signature was successfully verified. In any case, I will test your code ASAP and validate your solution. You have been most helpful since you you found out what was wrong initially! Many thanks!!

Comment: I did not have time to manually check your solution but your approach helped fix my issue because you did identify the cause of my issue. Many thanks!